# I want a pick list as avaiable in richfaces in jquery or any other, which is compatible with jsf2.0

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, user-interface, jsf-2

I want a pick list as available in richfaces in jquery or any other which is compatible with jsf2.0

But I don't want to use richfaces, icefaces or primefaces.

I am getting some of the similar components in jQuery but I can't directly bind them with `List` in `ManagedBean`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chosen JQuery is the good option, and it gives the selected value directly in the back bean.